# Can we have multiple CNAMES for a single Name?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I need this for load balancing. For example, I've two azure storage accounts (say `a` and `b`) and the blob addresses for those are `a.blob.core.windows.net` and `b.blob.core.windows.net`. Both of them store identical data. Now I need to provide a single external name (say `example.com`) which points to both the storage accounts and should work in round robin. This can be achieved if I create two CNAME entries in DNS as following and it resolves to one of them in round robing.

1. `example.com` CNAME `a.blob.core.windows.net`
2. `example.com` CNAME `b.blob.core.windows.net`

But I can not create two CNAME records for a single name in Windows DNS server.

So is it ever possible?

Comment: I can't check, but I don't think you can do this with CNAMES. Try A records instead.

Comment: @Dan The problem is going to be services that don't have a fixed IP, like an AWS Elastic Load Balancer. Given the `core.windows.net` I'd suspect a similar situation in Azure or something.

Comment: But with A records, I have to specify the IP address right? I prefer DNS names to IP addresses.

Comment: why would you want to do that? azure blob storage is already setup for high availability and geo redundancy.

Comment: @JTKH that was because blob has a download limit of 65MB/sec or so and if I want more download limit, I thought of using more than one blob.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Multiple CNAME records for the same fully-qualified domain name is a violation of the specs for DNS. Some versions of BIND would allow you to do this (some only if you specified the `multiple-cnames yes` option) and would round-robin load-balance between then but it's not technically legal.

There are not supposed to be resource records (RRs) with the same name as a CNAME and, to pick nits, that would include multiple identical CNAMEs. Quoth RFC 1034, Section 3.6.2:

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present;
>   this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot
>   be different. This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be used
>   without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

The letter-of-the RFC method to handle what you're doing would be with a single CNAME referring to a load-balanced "A" record.

Comment: See https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch10_07.htm#dns4-CHP-10-SECT-7.1 for more details.

Answer (score 17):

You cannot. A CNAME makes one record another name for another. If a record could have CNAMES for two names, it wouldn't be another name for either of them, but a name for something entirely new, making a CNAME entry inappropriate.

There's likely a good way to solve your outer problem though. For example, you can have multiple A records.

Comment: can I have one CName and one A Record for the website at the same time?

Comment: @amesh No you can't. You can't have a CNAME and A record with the same string identification, it's one or another. 
The best solution was given by David Schwartz. 
You can have multiple A records pointing to the same A records group.

Comment: `dig store.brave.com` has two CNAME records

Comment: @Aditya It shows only one CNAME for store.brave.com, brave.ogn.app. That is, itself a CNAME to a CNAME.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ahh I see. Thanks !